# How to count the total items under the parent sub category in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables below

subcategorytbl

```
 sub_id    sub_title     sub_parent_id
   1        For rent           0
   2        Car                1
   3        Motorcycle         1 
   4        For Sale           0 
   5        Boat               4
```

itemtbl

```
  item_id    sub_id
    1          2
    2          2  
    3          3
    4          1
    5          2
    6          5
```

Car and Motorcycle are under  For rent and Boat is under For Sale subcategory. Therefore,the result should be like this:

```
For Rent(5) 
- Car(3)
- Motorcycle(1)
For Sale(1) 
- Boat(1)
```

Below is my query:

```
  SELECT  count(*) as itemcount ,  sub_parent_id  from 
   subcategorytbl
  LEFT JOIN  itemtbl ON   subcategorytbl.sub_id=itemtbl.sub_id  
  GROUP BY   subcategorytbl.sub_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select concat(if(a.sub_parent_id>0," - ",""), a.sub_title,'(',count(itb.it_id),')') from subcategorytbl a inner join (select sub_id as sid,sub_id as chid from subcategorytbl where sub_parent_id=0 union
select sub_parent_id as sid,sub_id as chid from subcategorytbl where sub_parent_id>0
union select sub_id as sid,sub_id as chid from subcategorytbl where sub_parent_id>0
 ) b on b.sid=a.sub_id  
 inner join (select item_id as it_id,sub_id  as itsid from itemtbl) itb on itb.itsid=b.chid 
 group by a.sub_title order by a.sub_id;
```

Output

```
For rent(5)
 - Car(3)
 - Motorcycle (1)
For Sale(1)
 - Boat(1)
```

Comment: I never anticipated just this kind of query..  lol.. thanks man

Answer (score 2):

What you need here is the [`GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) option:

```
 SELECT  count(*) as itemcount ,  sub_parent_id  from 
   subcategorytbl
  LEFT JOIN  itemtbl ON   subcategorytbl.sub_id=itemtbl.sub_id  
  GROUP BY   subcategorytbl.sub_id WITH ROLLUP
```