# How to display the items under a sub category in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables.

categorytbl

```
cat_id    cat_name
  1       Vehicles
  2       Computers
```

subcategorytbl

```
 sub_id      sub_name         sub_parent_id    cat_id
   1         For Rent            0             1
   2         For Sale            0             1
   3         Car for Rent        1             1
   4         Car for Sale        2             1
   5         Motorcycle for Sale 2             1
   6         Boat                2             1
   7         Desktop             0             1
```

itemtbl

```
item_id  item_name       sub_id      
  1       Ferrari           3        
  2       Ford              3
  3       Isuzu             3
  4       GMC               4 
  5       Uncategorized     2
  6       Honda             5
```

From the above tables, I am trying to display the list of items, children and parent sub category. The result should be:

```
  For Rent(3) 
   Ferrari - car for Rent
   Ford    - Car For Rent
   Isuzu   - Car For Rent 

 FOR SALE(3)
   GMC           - Car for Sale
   Uncategorized - [empty]
   Honda         - Motorcycle for Sale
```

Here is my sql query:

```
  SELECT COUNT( itemtbl.cat_id ) AS cnt, categorytbl.cat_id AS cat_id
  FROM (
  categorytbl
   LEFT JOIN itemtbl ON itemtbl.cat_id = categorytbl.cat_id
   )
   LEFT JOIN subcategorytbl ON subcategorytbl.sub_id = itemtbl.sub_id
   GROUP BY cat_id
   ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: it might be easier to do some of this on the application level. which programming language are you using?

Comment: @FuzzyTree..  I am using PHP..

Comment: I have elaborated it here from this question .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021147/how-to-count-the-total-items-under-the-parent-sub-category-in-mysql

Comment: Instead of putting the content of the tables, put the sentences to create the tables and the insert. It would be easier for us to replicate your problem and find an answer

Answer (score 2):

I suggest querying the database for a list of items and doing the grouping in php using associative arrays. Comments below:

```
$sql = "select p.sub_name as parent_name,
s.sub_name, i.item_name
from itemtbl i
join subcategorytbl s on s.sub_id = i.sub_id
join subcategorytbl p on p.sub_id = s.sub_parent_id";

$rs = mysqli_query($sql);
$indexed_results = [];

// create an associative array where the key is 
// the parent sub i.e. For Rent etc
// and the value is an array of items
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $indexed_results[$r['parent_name']][] = $r;
}

// now loop through each group and display
foreach($indexed_results as $parent_name => $results) {
    print $parent_name . '('.count($results).")\n";

    foreach($results as $result) {
        print $result['item_name'] . ' - ' 
            . $result['sub_name'] . "\n";
    }
}
```